# Requesting different parameters using request.getParameter

Tags: java, android, jsp, servlets

hi i'm using this code from android to send a json to a servlet what works fine, and i was wondering how i could i send a different tag ie Tag2 to the servlet side, but still be able to handle the Tag1 safely on the servlet side

//aproximate desired code
//android side

```
...

url = new URL("http:// 10.0.2.2:8080 /Server/goTo?Tag1="+JSON);

...

url = new URL("http:// 10.0.2.2:8080 /Server/goTo?Tag2="+JSON);

...

//servlet side

...

jsonRequest= new JSONObject(request.getParameter("Tag1"));

...

jsonRequest= new JSONObject(request.getParameter("Tag"));

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ampersand:

```
url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/Server/goTo?Tag1="+JSON1+"&Tag2="+JSON2);
```

By the way, you have spaces in your url you need to remove.

Comment: thanks very much :) The spaces are there because stack overflow complains about having http://10.0.2.2:8080 when you ask a question. how would i be able to recive it on the servlet side for if i were to send one or the other or both.

Comment: Have you tried the url with both? It should just work unless you have an unescaped ampersand inside the first value.